# How does consistency imply that a heuristic is also admissible?

Tags: algorithms, shortest-path, heuristics

A heuristic function $h (n)$ is...

- *Consistent* if the estimated cost from node $n$ to the goal is no greater than the step cost to its successor $n'$ plus the estimated cost from the successor to the goal.
- *Admissible* if $h(n)$ never overestimates the true cost to the goal state.

The textbook for my Artificial Intelligence course states that consistency is stronger than admissibility but does not prove it, and I'm having trouble coming up with a mathematical explanation.

Comment: Take a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consistent_heuristic

Answer (score 14):

To proof the statement in your question, let us proof that *consistency* implies *admissibility* whereas the opposite is not necessarily true. This would make *consistency* a stronger condition than the latter.

*Consistency implies admissibility:*

Let me start by emphasizing that $h(t)=0$ if the heuristic function $h$ is *admissible* (where $t$ is a goal) since edge costs are assumed to be non-negative and thus, the optimal cost from one node to itself is necessarily 0. This certainly holds in case the heuristic function is *admissible* but we want to proof that *consistency* necessarily implies *admissibility*. For this, let us assume further that $h(t)=0$ for any goal ---and this fact will be used in the base case below.

The proof proceeds by induction:

**Base case**: take any predecessor of the goal node $t$. Let $n$ denote it, so that $t$ is a successor of $n$. If the heuristic function is *consistent*, then $h(n)\leq c(n,t) + h(t)=c(n,t) + 0 =c(n,t)$ and hence, $h$ behaves admissibly in this case.

Note that the base case does not assume that the edge $\langle n, t\rangle$ is necessarily the optimal solution from $n$ to $t$ and, indeed, there might be a different path from $n$ to $t$ with a lower cost. The importance of the base case, is that $h(n)\leq c(n,t)$ for all ancestors of node $t$! This result will be reused in the induction step.

**Induction step**: consider a node $n$. The optimal cost to reach the goal $t$ from $n$, $h^*(n)$, is computed as: $\min_{m\in\mathrm{SCS(n)}}\{c(n,m)+h^*(m)\}$, where $\mathrm{SCS}(n)$ is the set of successors of node $n$. As *consistency* is assumed by hypothesis, then $h(n)\leq c(n,n')+h(n')$. Furthermore, as $h(n')\leq h^*(n')$ is assumed by the induction step then $h(n)\leq c(n,n')+h^*(n')$  and this is true for all successors $n'$ of node $n$. In other words: $h(n)\leq \min_{m\in\mathrm{SCS(n)}}\{c(n,m)+h^*(m)\} = h^*(n)$, so that $h(n)\leq h^*(n)$.

*Admissibility does not necessarily imply consistency:*

For this, a simple example suffices. Consider a graph which consists of a single path with 10 nodes: $\langle n_0, n_1, n_2, ..., n_9\rangle$, where the goal is $n_9$. Let us assume *wlog* that all edge costs are equal to 1. Obviously $h^*(n_0)=9$, and let us make $h(n_0)=8$, $h(n_i)=1, 1\leq i<9$ and $h(n_9)=0$. Clearly, the heuristic function is *addmissible*:

1. $h(t)=0$
2. $h(n_i)=1\leq h^*(n_i)=(9-i)$, $\forall i, 1\leq i<9$.
3. Finally, $h(n_0)=8\leq h^*(n_0)=9$.

However, $h(n)$ is not *consistent* and $h(n_0)=8 > c(n_0, n_1)+h(n_1)=1+1=2$.

Hope this helps,

Comment: why are edge costs assumed to be non negative?

Comment: Well, I did just because it is conventional to do so. Heuristics are usually applied with non-negative edge costs. Good question indeed ... !

Comment: `h(n)≤c(n,t)` does not trivially imply that `h(n)≤h*(h)`. Can you explain why this is so, since you need to prove that to assume h(n′)≤h*(n′) by the induction step. [Here] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64596325/proof-of-consistent-heuristic-implies-admissible-condition) is a possible explanation.

Comment: Not sure I get your point Federico ... it seems to me you are asking that it is not trivial to show that $h(n)\leq c(n,t)$ necessarily implies that $h(n)\leq h^*(n)$, ... well the first part is known as consistency. Second is known as admissibility and the whole question is all about that. The answer I provided is an attempt to prove precisely that ... Maybe there are obscure or even a wrong point in my reply ... is there?

Comment: @FedericoCiuffardi $h(n') \le h^\star(n')$ is the induction hypothesis. Throughout the proof we assume that $h(\cdot)$ is consistent, i.e. $h(a) \le c(a,b) + h^\star(b)$ for any $a$ and any of its successors $b$. The induction step then shows that $h(n') \le h^\star(n')$ implies $h(n) \le h^\star(n)$, i.e. admissibility of the $h(\cdot)$ at $n'$ implies admissibility of $h(\cdot)$ as any of its predecessors $n$. Recall the induction is working backwards from the goal node.

Comment: Thank you for your answers! I think I understand what you are saying, but for the inductive step to make sense, the inductive hypothesis has to be proven by the base case for some element. The base case proves `h(n)≤=c(n,t)` (`n predecessor of t`) and the inductive hypothesis is `h(n′)≤h*(n′)`. As I understand it, for this to be correct that `h(n)≤=c(n,t)` implies `h(n)≤=h*(n)`  should be proved for `n predecessor of t`. Maybe I am missing something.